# I messed up a backup script and now have File1.txt/File1.txt for a lot of files. How do I delete the directory and keep the file? OS is Ubuntu

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, backup

For example, I have:

```
~/backup/File1.txt/File1.txt
```

But I want to have:

```
~/backup/File1.txt
```

The directory File1.txt is empty except for the file File1.txt. To manually solve the problem, I've moved File1.txt to a File1-folder, then mv File1.txt ../ then deleted File1-folder, but I would like to automate that.

Comment: I once wrote a python script to move all files in all subdirectories of a given directory into the the base directory. you could then delete all the (now empty) sub-directories. if you would like me to share it, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways. For example:

```bsh
    cd ~/backup # Move to the backup folder
    TEMPDIR=$HOME/backup-tmp # Temporary directory
    mkdir -p "$TEMPDIR" # Ensure it exists
    for contents in *; do # Iterate all the contents of the folder, which are folders but should be files (note: we assume none of them start with .)
       mv "$contents/$contents" "$TEMPDIR" # Move the subfile to the temporary folder
       rmdir "$contents" # Now we can remove the empty dir
       mv "$TEMPDIR/$contents" .  # Move back to the backup dir
    done
    rmdir "$TEMPDIR" # We are done with the temporary directory
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Angel said, there are a number of ways.  I think his is overly complex.  Here is a simpler version.

```
mv ~/backup ~/backup-wrong   
mkdir ~/backup
mv ~/backup-wrong/*/*.txt ~/backup
rm -r ~backup-wrong
```

The key line above is line 3, which matches all files ending in .txt in any subdirectories of ~/backup-wrong to the new backup directory.

Comment: Note: your way is prone to `argument list too long`, while the "overly complex" one is immune.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir ~/backup2
find ~/backup -type f -print -exec mv {} ~/backup2 \;
rm -r ~/backup
mv ~/backup2 ~/backup
```

Comment: not sure about *argument list too long* but i believe you can speed up *find* without *-print* and terminate with `+` (instead `\;`)